# Revision not found in React-Native,Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to debug my app on my android phone. When i first build my app with:

```
sudo react-native run-android
```

It builds perfectly, but when I changed my code and saved, it doesn't reload and I need to build over and over again with every change. HMR is active, and tried to press 'Reload' on my Dev Menu, but it doesn't reload. Here is extra information:

- using Visual Studio Code.
- Android version of my phone: 6.0.1
- Connection:Via USB.
- USB Debugging:Enabled and Allowed to this computer.
- using Linux.
- [image: Error page in Android phone.]

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hiworld",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.50.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

if you need anything else, i'll edit this post.

Comment: Could it be related to using `sudo`? Does running `react-native run-android` without `sudo` change anything?

Comment: it gives PermissionError without sudo. This has its own long steps but sudo avoids these.